# Using a addEventListener to call a forEach function

Tags: javascript

So I cant find any sources online that shows an eventListener triggering a function by click that is forEach based I know i'm doing something wrong here so can any one point me to the right direction.

This is my code

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){

var numbers = [4, 9, 16, 25];

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',numbers.forEach(myFunction))

function myFunction(item, index) {

  //create a new h1 element 
  var newH1 = document.createElement('h1'); 
  //
  
  //Insert content in the h1
  var innerH1 = document.createTextNode(item); 
  //
  
  //Add the text node to the newly created h1
  newH1.appendChild(innerH1);  
  //
  
  //Add the newly created element and its content into the DOM 
  document.body.insertBefore(newH1,document.body.secondChild);
  //
}

});
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
```

Comment: Add `})` to end of code

Comment: What is your expected end result

Comment: `secondChild` isn’t a real thing. The rest looks OK

Comment: The problem is, that `addEventListener` expects a function reference/expression as the second argument, `forEach` returns `undefined`, hence no action is executed on a button click. Notice, that the iteration is executed immediately at the time you're attaching the listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to put `numbers.forEach(myFunction);` to a function inside the event, like this:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

    var numbers = [4, 9, 16, 25];

    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
        numbers.forEach(myFunction);
    });

    function myFunction(item, index) {

        //create a new h1 element 
        var newH1 = document.createElement('h1');
        //

        //Insert content in the h1
        var innerH1 = document.createTextNode(item);
        //

        //Add the text node to the newly created h1
        newH1.appendChild(innerH1);
        //

        //Add the newly created element and its content into the DOM 
        document.body.insertBefore(newH1, document.body.secondChild);
        //

    }

});
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
```

---

Syntax:

```
selector.addEventListener(event, function () {
    // implement...
});
```